# How to get scroll values of a select dropdown inside a modal

Tags: angularjs, scroll, modal-dialog

I have a select box which will load more than 3k values in it. Due to more values performance has got affected. So I tried to load values based on the scroll. But nothing worked for me.

The below HTML code is inside modal

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<select select2 data-placeholder="Program Name(s)" class="form-control scroll" ng- 
model="getProgramName" when-scrolled = "loadMore()" id="scroll" multiple>
<option value="{{progname}}" ng-repeat="progname in segmentList | limitTo:numberToDisplay">
{{progname | splitMak}}
</option>
</select>
</div
```

JS FIle:

```
$scope.openModelrepoName = function (ev, rowObj) {
try {
APIFactory.getAllFuncPackSrcArtifacts(repoNameObj, function (response) {
if (response.status) {
$mdDialog.show({
controller: dataFuntionalPartner,
templateUrl: 'html/templates/dataFunctionalPartner.template.html',
controllerAs: 'vmid',
parent: angular.element(document.body),
targetEvent: ev,
clickOutsideToClose: false,
fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen, // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
locals: {
"rowObj": rowObj,
"segmentList" : response.data,
"repoNameObj" : repoNameObj
 }
 })
 } else {
 Toaster.sayError(response.errorMessage)
 }
 })
 } catch (err) { }
 }

 function dataFuntionalPartner($scope, $mdDialog, rowObj,segmentList,repoNameObj) {
 $scope.numberToDisplay = 20;
 $scope.segmentList = segmentList
 
 $scope.loadMore = function (event) {
 if ($scope.numberToDisplay + 20 < $scope.segmentList.length) {
 $scope.numberToDisplay += 20;
 } else {
 $scope.numberToDisplay = $scope.segmentList.length;
 }
 }
```

My Directive:

```
 app.directive("whenScrolled", function(){
 return{      
 restrict: 'A',
 link: function(scope, elem, attrs){  
 console.log(elem)    
    // we get a list of elements of size 1 and need the first element
 raw = elem[0];
  
    // we load more elements when scrolled past a limit
 elem.bind("scroll", function(){
 if(raw.scrollTop+raw.offsetHeight+5 >= raw.scrollHeight){
 scope.loading = true;
        
 // we can give any function which loads more elements into the list
 scope.$apply(attrs.whenScrolled);
 }
 });
 }
 }
 });
```

My problem here is the above directive working only while initializing. and it is not working on any scroll action is done.

Comment: There are no cross browser supported events on a `<select>` that you can use to do this. You might consider using a typeahead/autocomplete module instead. That many choices is far too many for a user to consume in a friendly way

Comment: Is there some heirarchy to the data? category/subcategory/items? Rethink this interface... it is a poor user experience waiting to happen.

Comment: No there is no category/subcategory